# Vue.js as ExpressJS view engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, vue.js

I am looking for something like [React for ExpressJS](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views) but working with Vue.js.

I have problem with passing data from database (mongoose) to view. As for now, I am using handlebars view engine to pass data with mustache to script tag and then passing them to vue files through window object, but I don't think it's a best way to do it.

Have somebody used vue.js , express.js and mongoose for SPA applications?

Comment: Very old thread, but maybe this would do the trick now: https://github.com/express-vue/express-vue

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is anything to use Vue.js with the Express view engine API.  Nevertheless, Vue 2.0 (Release Candidate) supports server rendering.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-server-renderer

The following link has an example using Express.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/next/packages/vue-server-renderer/README.md

Comment: Though it seems like another valid option for you is to just make an ajax request for the data from your client side app.